# Validation rule to run on a particular role but exclude 1 username under that same role

Tags: validation-rule, opportunity, validation

Trying to create a validation rule to stop a particular Roles (example Role A, Role B and Role C) from changing info on a closed opportunity.

I have 1 user which I want to bypass this validation rule but has the Role C - how do I go about creating this part of the rule?

I have tried by using the username as the data point:

```
AND(PRIORVALUE(IsClosed) = True,
&& (OR($UserRole.Name = "Role A",
$UserRole.Name = "Role B",
$UserRole.Name = "Role C" AND $User.Username <> "ExceptionUser@Salesforce.com"))
```

Any help will be much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to change this

```
 AND $User.Username <> "ExceptionUser@Salesforce.com"
```

to this

```
 AND NOT($User.Username = 'ExceptionUser@Salesforce.com')
```

Comment: Thanks for helping :) Unfortunately it hasn't solved the issue. Not sure how to do this as 'exceptionUser@Salesforce.com' has the role 'Role C'. I want all Role C users to be faced with the validation except for exceptionUser@Salesforce.com

Comment: Maybe the username is misspelled?

Comment: I have just double checked and it is still stopping that user from making the changes. I wonder if it's just picking up that she is is part of Role C?

Comment: maybe. because I tested the condition I sent and it works fine. try to remove all your conditions and add them 1 by 1 to make sure all is correct and it comes to username evaluation

Comment: amazing! it worked as you said so thank you!  (it was my error for forgetting my next steps with configurations)

Comment: You're welcome @AwesomeAdmin8